# GeoServer access by others

Tags: geoserver

I have shapefiles in a PostGIS database hosted in the GeoServer. I access my page with my data using localhost URL. However I need to give access to the page to other people. How can I do that?

Comment: you'll need to use the hostname of your machine

Comment: Find out what is your IP (`ipconfig` in cmd) or connection status in mac, and make sure Geoserver ports are not blocked by firewall. Replace localhost with your IP.

Comment: I am using Windows. To run my webmap I use http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/my_page.html. However I want to open in other machine. Yours explanations are correct for this?